# Change Column Type within a For Loop in R for many similar data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to change a column type from 'chr' to 'date' after reading csv files with the same structure within a folder

The code works fine to read the csv and assign data from each file to an individual variable, however, it shows an error when trying to change column "date" into a date type.

```
# Code to Read CSV files within a folder and change column type to date type

mydir <- "~/Desktop//Data/Downloads"
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(myfiles)) {
    nam <- paste("price",i, sep = ".")
    assign(nam, read.csv(file = myfiles[i] , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) # Code until here works fine
    price.i$date <- as.Date(price.i$date) # this part of the code generates the error
}

# Error
Error in as.Date(price.i$date) : object 'price.i' not found

# Example of Data read from each CSV file 
   str(price.1)
   'data.frame':    2195 obs. of  3 variables:
   symbol : chr "CAR" "CAR" "CAR"
   date : chr "2020-01-02" "2020-01-03" "2020-01-06"
   adjusted : num 16.5 16.6 16.7

# Expected Result
str(price.1)
   'data.frame':    2195 obs. of  3 variables:
   symbol : chr "CAR" "CAR" "CAR"
   date    : Date, format: "2020-01-02" "2020-01-03" "2020-01-06"
   adjusted : num 16.5 16.6 16.7
```

Is it possible to 'Subset' the variable within the loop to change the column type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lapply` to read the files in a loop and change the column type.

```
result <- lapply(myfiles, function(x) {
  df <- read.csv(file = x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df$date <- as.Date(df$date) 
  df
})
```

Do you really need data as separate objects in global environment ? You can keep them in a list which is present in `result`, it is easier to manage data in that way. However, if you still need them separately you can use `list2env`

```
names(result) <- paste0('price', seq_along(result))
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak, it is what I was trying to achieve!. You are right, having results stored in a list should be easier. However what I want to achieve is create a plot using plotly for each of the data frames within the list, but I am not sure how to achieve that as I am pretty new with plotly and thought having each of the data frames separately would help me for now.